# Nodes fail to start due to errors in loading scheduled tasks

Tags: plugins, dolphindb, pyzmq, nested-function

In both standalone server and single-machine cluster modes, an error is reported when nodes are started, which is shown as follows:

```
Failed to unmarshall the job [..]. Can't recognize function zmq::getSubJobStat. Invalid message format
```

I used the `zmq` plugin in this scheduled job. But instead of loading it in the main function, I wrapped the code for loading it into a separate function, which is then called by the main function.

The reason for the error may be that the main function cannot resolve the plugin.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Check if the plugin is installed and configured correctly. Make sure that the plugin is installed in the correct directory and that its configuration is set up properly.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods.

Method 1:

Modify the configuration file by adding the following parameters in dolphindb.cfg (standalone) or cluster.cfg (cluster).

```
preloadModules=plugins::zmq,plugins::xxx
```

Restart the node or cluster after modification. The `zmq` plugin will be preloaded to the system.

Modify it online to load plugins via `loadModule("plugins::zmq")`.

Method 2:

Remove the jobEditLog.meta file from the data/node/sysmgment path and restart the node.

This method is suitable for tests. After this operarion, all scheduled tasks are removed and need to be resubmitted.